# Function of several variables whose hessian is a Hankel matrix

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, fourier-analysis, hankel-matrices, hessian

First of all, let me apologize because I asked this question a few days ago on https://math.stackexchange.com, but I did not get any reply.

I am studying a function $f:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$, whose Hessian $H_{i,j} = \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x_i \partial x_j}$ has Hankel symmetry, namely $H_{i,j} = h_{i+j}$.

This is true for all points of $\mathbb{R}^n$.
How can I translate this into an interesting statement about $f$ ?

For context, my particular function whose Hessian is Hankel is heavily related to Fourier transforms, so I was not very surprised to learn that the two concepts are connected (see [arXiv:1402.5287](https://arxiv.org/abs/1402.5287) for instance).

Thanks,

Comment: Perhaps you can explain what $h_{i+j}$ means?  And what kind of statement about $f$ are you looking for?  You mention Fourier transformations: are you perhaps looking for conditions under which the latter exists?

Comment: What I mean is $H_{i,j}$ only depends on the value of $i+j$ == >https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hankel_matrix

Comment: And what I am looking for ... difficult to know for sure. If the Hessian were positive definite, then the function is convex. If the Hessian is zero, then the function is linear. Something along those lines.